# Insert new Records from one table to another table using Minus

Tags: sql, plsql, bulkinsert

I am inserting records in table1 and It will be inserted into table 2. Now if I will insert new records into table1 then only new records should be populated into table2. For this we can use minus concept as both tables are not purged out. But is it proper to use minus concept means suppose both table already have 100 000 records available. in table 1 I am inserting more 100 000 records. So minus is useful to use here or we have to use some another concept?

Comment: You could use a [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) statement instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tony Andrews said in the comments, you want to use a merge statement here.

Here's the basic syntactic use:

```
MERGE into <target table>
USING
    <souce table/view/result of subquery>
ON
    <match condition>
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    <update clause>
    <delete clause>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    <insert clause>
```

Extremely powerful especially in warehousing.